# GraphQL and MongoDB different schemas

Tags: mongodb, graphql

I am learning GraphQL and MongoDB to make a basic api with posts and users. In GraphQL I have:

```
type Query {

    user(username: String!): User
}

type User {
    id: ID!
    username: String!
    posts: [Post!]!
}


type Post {
    id: ID!
    author: User!
    text: String!
}
```

and in the database the schema is different. For each User, I store the posts as an array of the posts' IDs, and for each Post, the author is stored as the user's ID.

Now, suppose that I try query to get a User's posts:

When I get their posts from the database, it will give me the IDs of the posts rather than all the info associated with the posts, so it doesn't match the schema defined I defined for GraphQL.

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "posts": [ "1", "2", "3"]
    }
  }
}
```

What I want is for it be able to get info of the posts like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "posts": [
        {
          "id": "1"
          "text": "abc"
        },
        {
          "id": "2"
          "text": "def"
        },
        {
          "id": "3"
          "text": ghi"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am thinking of getting the data from the database and making the array of Posts myself and send that. I think this uses a lot of unnecessary database calls and memory for each of the Posts, so is this an acceptable approach or is there a better way to solve this? I was thinking of storing the data in the MongoDB differently but I don't know what I could do.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit subjective because there are many "correct" ways to implement both GraphQL and Mongo schemas.

Personally I don't see how storing post ids at the user level helps you very much. Since each post has an author id it's easy enough to find all posts authored by a user.

I recommend removing the `posts` array from your MongoDB user model and then writing a resolver for `posts` at the user level that finds all the related posts.

```
User: {
  posts: (parent,args,context) => {
    return posts.find({authorId: parent._id);
  }
}
```

Or more succinctly:

```
User: {
  posts: ({_id}) => posts.find({authorId: _id)
}
```